# Is there a way in the ViewModel to know which fragment that call a method in this ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

In the ViewModel, i want to know which fragment that call a method in this ViewModel

Is there a way to know that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is any better way but you just need to pass fragment's tag to function parameter.

Comment: any other way ? because i have share viewmodel / usecase that being use from several fragment